# How do I get a DataTable of all my TFS Changesets

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tfs, visual-studio-2015

**I am trying to populate a Datatable with details of my TFS project changesets.**

I am trying to get:

- Each row to represent a single change submission
- Filtered to only display change submissions that were entered between two specified dates.

The DataTable is set up with the following columns:

- folder_path
- filename
- project_name
- username
- datetime_entered
- message

I'm hoping to end up with something like this:

[image]

My main issue is that I don't know where to find the change submission data to iterate through to populate my DataTable.

Comment: What is it that is not working, and what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: My guess is that the question can be significantly shortened so it appears to be less intimidating. Most people who know TFS aren't going to need details on how your application uses the data.  Just a thought - if it helps, that's good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

Add references to the following:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
>
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common

Code for Form1.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TFSAPItest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<Changeset> BaseChangesets { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            TxtDateFrom.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            TxtDateTo.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            
        }

        private void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime DateFrom = DateTime.Parse(TxtDateFrom.Text);

            DateTime DateTo = DateTime.Parse(TxtDateTo.Text);
            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("file_path");
            dt.Columns.Add("filename");
            dt.Columns.Add("project");
            dt.Columns.Add("username");
            dt.Columns.Add("datetime_entered");
            dt.Columns.Add("message");

            List<Changeset> FilteredChangesets = new List<Changeset>();

            foreach (Changeset c in BaseChangesets)
            {
                if(c.CreationDate > DateFrom && c.CreationDate < DateTo)
                {
                    FilteredChangesets.Add(c);

                }

            }

            foreach (Changeset c in FilteredChangesets)
            {
                List<Change> Changes = c.Changes.ToList<Change>();
                
                if (Changes != null && Changes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Change ch in Changes)
                    {
                        if (ch.Item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                            string ServerItem = ch.Item.ServerItem.Substring(ch.Item.ServerItem.IndexOf('/') + 1, ch.Item.ServerItem.Length - ch.Item.ServerItem.IndexOf('/') - 1);

                            dr["file_path"] = ServerItem.Substring(0, ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/'));
                            dr["filename"] = ServerItem.Substring(ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, ServerItem.Length - ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/') - 1);
                            dr["project"] = ServerItem.Substring(0, ServerItem.IndexOf('/'));
                            dr["username"] = c.Committer;
                            dr["datetime_entered"] = c.CreationDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
                            dr["message"] = c.Comment;

                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            
            DgvResults.DataSource = dt;
            
        }

        private void BtnGetInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://example.com:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection"));

            ProjectCollection.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);

            var vcs = ProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            VersionSpec versionFrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C529", null);

            VersionSpec versionTo = VersionSpec.Latest;

            string serverPath = @"$/";

            List<Changeset> Changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(serverPath,
              VersionSpec.Latest,
              0,
              RecursionType.Full,
              null,
              versionFrom,
              versionTo,
              Int32.MaxValue,
              true,
              false
              ).Cast<Changeset>().ToList<Changeset>();

            BaseChangesets = Changesets;

            if(BaseChangesets != null)
            {
                GrpDateFilter.Enabled = true;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The interesting part is in the BtnGetInformation_Click method.

It's a bit slow, because it trawls through the whole TFS, but it works!